# How to include new line and spaces in pdf creation using php?

Tags: php, pdf, nl2br

I am trying to create a pdf document using php.

But, I can't get new line in the pdf.

`nl2br` is not working so I have used

```
$newadd =  nl2br(str_replace('\r', ' ', $inputSafe['address']));
```

Now I got the correct output in html as

```
Naduvilachirayil House,
Anaprampal North P.O,
Thalavady
```

But in pdf, I am getting only

```
Naduvilachirayil House,<br>Anaprampal North P.O,<br>Thalavady.
```

Comment: Unless you're using an HTML->PDF library, `<br>` means nothing to PDF and will be treated as plaintext.

Answer (score 0):

see if this helps:

```
$newadd = nl2br(str_replace("\n\r", ' ', $inputSafe['address']));
```